# Which correlation method do I use?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, correlation, coefficients

For a project, I have a dataset:
Eruptions   Waiting

0  3.600        79
1  1.800        54
2  3.333        74
3  2.283        62
4  4.533        85

and was instructed to turn it into a Seaborn pairplot:
[image]

I am then asked: What correlation method should I use based on this graph. I am stuck between Pearson and Spearman. I am unsure which I should use. Based on this, I am also asked: Are the durations correlated with the waiting time between eruptions? Any correlation >= .7 is a correlation. Please help

Comment: I would default to using Pearson correlation, unless there the data deviates strongly from normality. I would say this example doesn't justify using Spearman.

Comment: I would use Pearson. Maybe this answer will help you: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8071/how-to-choose-between-pearson-and-spearman-correlation#:~:text=The%20difference%20between%20the%20Pearson,measurements%20taken%20from%20ordinal%20scales.